# Can't Seem To Save Off Data Returned From Call To http.get() Method in Angular 6

Tags: angular, http, get, angular6

all:

I am a newcomer to Angular 6 and have been learning about how to display data using a table. I haven’t had any issues with static data – that is, data in an array statically defined as in the numerous examples that seem to be online all over the place. Where I’m baffled is working with data returned from the (new) HttpClient provided by Angular since Version 4.

I have defined an object with 5 properties, all stored in a MySQL table on a different server. A PHP script on that server returns an array of 25 JSON objects with those properties defined.

The method I use to call this service is:

**table-demo-components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FltdataHttpService } from '../fltdatahttp.service';

// Sorting support
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';    // new decorator
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';

// Data are supplied by a service

var FLIGHTS = new Array();

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-demo',
  templateUrl: './table-demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-demo.component.css']
})
export class TableDemoComponent implements OnInit {

  // specify which columns are to show
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'flightNum',
    'destinationCity',
    'schedTime',
    'actualTime',
    'remarks'
  ];     // NOTE: these are the columns/properties as strings!

  // this is how you handle sorted data
  flightDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.flightDataService.FLIGHTS);       
  //flightDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(FLIGHTS);       // note the difference

  dummyNum: number;

  // Add decorators for sort and pagination
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;  
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.flightDataSource.sort = this.sort;

  }

  // Inject HTTP support - flightDataService - not flightDataSource
  constructor(public flightDataService: FltdataHttpService) {
    console.log(">>> constructor fired; flightDataService = " + flightDataService);
  }

  // Support for pagination - note it comes in this and not ngOnInit()

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //************************************ 
    // IT MUST BE IN THIS ORDER!
    //************************************ 

    // flightDataSource is set here
    FLIGHTS = this.flightDataService.getFlightData();       // get the actual data first
    console.log(">>> FLIGHTS local = " + FLIGHTS.length);

    this.flightDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(FLIGHTS);   // then pass it to the source       

    this.flightDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;   // then attached the paginator
    this.flightDataSource.sort = this.sort;             // and last, the sort option
  }

}
```

Elsewhere, I have a service defined to call the **http.get** method:

**fltdatahttp.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { FlightInfo } from './table-demo/flight-info';

var newFlight;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FltdataHttpService {

  public httpData: any;                  

  public FLIGHTS: FlightInfo[] = [];

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { 
    //this.getFlightData();
  }

  public getFlightDataLocally(): FlightInfo[]  {

    console.log(">>> getFlightDataLocally() fired");

    this.FLIGHTS = [
      {flightNum: '145', destinationCity: 'Chicago Midway', schedTime: '17:35', actualTime: 'ON TIME', remarks: 'AMBASSADOR SERVICE'},
      {flightNum: '365', destinationCity: 'Toronto Pearson', schedTime: '17:46', actualTime: 'ON TIME', remarks: 'NON-STOP'},
      {flightNum: '277', destinationCity: 'Montreal Trudeau', schedTime: '17:51', actualTime: 'ON TIME', remarks: 'NON-STOP'},
      {flightNum: '980', destinationCity: 'New York LaGuardia', schedTime: '17:58', actualTime: 'ON TIME', remarks: 'AMBASSADOR SERVICE'},
      {flightNum: '671', destinationCity: 'Los Angeles Intl', schedTime: '18:02', actualTime: 'ON TIME', remarks: 'VIA PHOENIX'},
    ];

    return this.FLIGHTS;

  }

  public getFlightData(): FlightInfo[] {                // timing issue? web lag?

    console.log(">>> getFlightData(): ");

    this.http.get("http://localhost/flights.php", { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(data => {

      this.httpData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(">>> resp = " + data.toString());

      for (var f = 0; f < this.httpData.flights.length; f++) {

        console.log(">>> creating element - " + this.httpData.flights[f].flightNum);

        newFlight = new FlightInfo();
        newFlight.flightNum = this.httpData.flights[f].flightNum; 
        newFlight.destinationCity = this.httpData.flights[f].destinationCity;
        newFlight.schedTime = this.httpData.flights[f].schedTime;
        newFlight.actualTime = this.httpData.flights[f].actualTime;
        newFlight.remarks = this.httpData.flights[f].remarks;

        this.FLIGHTS.push(newFlight);
      }

    });

    // A static array assigning a series of new FlightInfo objects here can be seen
    // by Angular Material, outside the .subscribe() method above. Inside, the same
    // for loop causes NOTHING to happen to the this.FLIGHTS array.

    return this.FLIGHTS;

  }

}
```

The first method, getFlightDataLocally(), performs as I expected – when the HTML page appears, I see the five defined objects.

But when I use **getFlightData()**, the second method, the resulting table/array is empty. Even more confusing, the console.log messages indicate a firing sequence that’s non-intuitive to me:

**Console Output:**

```
>>> getFlightData():                 table-demo.component.ts:58 
>>> FLIGHTS local = 0                fltdatahttp.service.ts:59 
>>> resp = { "flights" : [
{
   "flightNum" : "345",
   "destinationCity" : "CHICAGO MIDWAY",
   "schedTime" : "09:30",
   "actualTime" : "ON TIME",
   "remarks" : "AMBASSADOR SERVICE"
},
{
   "flightNum" : "712",
   "destinationCity" : "MILWAUKEE",
   "schedTime" : "09:44",
   "actualTime" : "ON TIME",
   "remarks" : "AMBASSADOR SERVICE"
},
{
   "flightNum" : "910",
   "destinationCity" : "CHAMPAIGN/URBANA",
   "schedTime" : "09:56",
   "actualTime" : "ON TIME",
   "remarks" : "AMBASSADOR SERVICE"
},
{
   "flightNum" : "118",
   "destinationCity" : "HOUSTON HOBBY",
   "schedTime" : "10:00",
   "actualTime" : "ON TIME",
   "remarks" : "AMBASSADOR SERVICE"
},
{
   "flightNum" : "627",
   "destinationCity" : "MIAMI",
   "schedTime" : "10:03",
   "actualTime" : "ON TIME",
   "remarks" : "NONSTOP"
},
...
...
}
]} fltdatahttp.service.ts:63 
>>> creating element - 345
    fltdatahttp.service.ts:63 
>>> creating element - 712 
   fltdatahttp.service.ts:63 
>>> creating element - 910 
   fltdatahttp.service.ts:63 
>>> creating element - 118 
   fltdatahttp.service.ts:63 
>>> creating element - 627 
   fltdatahttp.service.ts:63 
...
```

What I expected getFlightData() to do was to return an array with all 25 of the JSON objects – but all it appears to do is return nothing, and it appears to be some kind of sequence/timing issue I can’t wrap my head around. The data variable in the first arrow function for .subscribe clearly receives data, but attempting to save it off to local variable this.httpData hasn’t worked.

Can someone explain what will make it possible to successfully call a second web server from an Angular script, and to have any data returned actually remain rather than to disappear?

What have I got wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Angular's `http.get()` and `http.post()` methods process asynchronously.

Thus, while Angular is waiting for `get` to do its thing, Angular will continue on to the next line of code *without waiting*.

The `FLIGHTS` array was initialized to be empty. The `get` hasn't finished the api call yet, so the array is still empty. Angular is not going to wait for `get` to finish, therefore Angular returned the empty array.

`http.get` and `http.post` return `Observables`: an interface that lets you set a callback to run whenever `http` finishes.

Therefore, your `subscribe` method is called whenever `http.get` finishes. It could be in 300 ms, or 4 hours. We don't know.  But when it does finish, the callback is executed. This will result in `FLIGHTS` being populated *at that time*.

**Well, how do I use http.get's results?**

Well, you are halfway there.  You already fill `FltdatahttpService.FLIGHTS` whenever the api call finishes.  So instead of returning `FLIGHTS`, you can consume it directly.

Example:

`<div *ngFor="let flight of FltdatahttpService.FLIGHTS">
    <div>{{flight.name}}</div>
</div>`

Angular is smart enough to know when `FltdatahttpService.FLIGHTS` has changed, and will update the DOM accordingly.

However, as you are manipulating the results in the component it may be better to return the subscription directly from the service.  Then you can let whatever consumer you like do any extra processing it needs.

```
export class FltdataHttpService {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) { 
      private http: HttpClient
    }

    public getFlightData(): Observable<Array<FlightInfo> {

        //Angular can auto-deserialize JSON into objects for you
        return this.http.get<Array<FlightInfo>>(
            "http://localhost/flights.php",
            { responseType: 'application/json' });

        //returning the raw Observable.
        //The consumer can get a copy of the results by adding a subscription.
        //Thus, each consumer can do any extra processing required.
    }
}
```

And the consumer:

```
export class TableDemoComponent implements OnInit {

    //FLIGHTS won't be filled until the service call finishes.
    public flightDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(new Array<FlightData>());

    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

    ngOnInit() {
        //Init stuff here
    }

    constructor(
      public flightDataService: FltdataHttpService
    ) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        //Start the service call.
        //Do stuff when it finishes.

        this.flightDataService.getFlightData()
            .subscribe(
               flightData => this.onFlightDataChanged(flightData),
               error => this.onError(error)
             );
    }

    private onFlightDataChanged(flightData: Array<FlightData>): void {
        //the service call has finished.
        //Recreating the table using the fresh data from the service

        this.flightDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(flightData);
        this.flightDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.flightDataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }

    private onError(error: any): void {
        //something broke.
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```